# Can I query a JSON field from Crashlytics as a "where" directive in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, crashlytics

I've searched SO for this and found a number of similar questions, but I can't quite figure out how to apply them to my scenario.

We have Google Crashlytics linked to BigQuery.

Given the following table data (many columns deleted for clarity):

```
TABLE firebase_crashlytics.com_foo_ios

is_fatal | application
======================
true     | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"53"},{"v":"0.9.1"}]}}
false    | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"71"},{"v":"1.0.0"}]}}
true     | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"72"},{"v":"1.0.1"}]}}
```

I've tried a lot of the suggestions, but can't seem to make this work.

I want to query the com_foo_ios table for all records for which `is_fatal` equals `true`, and the application version (the second array element of `application`) is higher than `1.0.0`. Alternatively, I could use the build number as that is unique to versions.

So my question is:

Can this be done via an SQL query without having to write custom functions as suggested in [Berlyant's reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60153030/1227012), which didn't work for me.

Interestingly, the errors I see indicate that the two elements of the `application` array are identified as `build_version` and `display_name`. I've tried using those in queries as well, to no avail.

Using the above sample data, can anyone suggest a straightforward way of querying this info?

Comment: Can you clarify the error you encountered when you used the custom function? Can you elaborate where do `build_version` and `display_name` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using the above sample data, can anyone suggest a straightforward way of querying this info?

```
select t.*, 
  json_extract_scalar(_[offset(0)], '$.v') as col1,
  json_extract_scalar(_[offset(1)], '$.v') as col2
from your_table t,
unnest([struct(json_extract_array(application, '$.v.f') as _)])
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select true is_fatal, '{"v":{"f":[{"v":"53"},{"v":"0.9.1"}]}}' application union all
  select false, '{"v":{"f":[{"v":"71"},{"v":"1.0.0"}]}}' union all
  select true, '{"v":{"f":[{"v":"72"},{"v":"1.0.1"}]}}' 
)
```

output is

[image]

> Hmm, dumping the data model shows 'application: STRUCT<build_version STRING, display_version STRING>'

so looks like your table schema is actually like in below sample

```
with your_table as (
  select true is_fatal, struct('53' as buildversion, '0.9.1' as display_version) application union all
  select false, struct('71' as buildversion, '1.0.0' as display_version) union all
  select true, struct('72' as buildversion, '1.0.1' as display_version) 
)
```

If so - use below to get to particular field(s)

```
select is_fatal, application.*
from your_table t
```

with output

[image]

Comment: OK, I tried your suggestion but am getting an error. I had to prefix 'application' in the last line with `t.`, as the application on its own couldn't be resolved.

When I run the query (via DataGrip), I get the following error:

```
 Error executing query job. Message: No matching signature for function JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY for argument types: STRUCT<build_version STRING, display_version STRING>, STRING. Supported signature: JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(STRING, [STRING])
```

Comment: sure. so does it work for you then?

Comment: Not yet. I updated my comment.

Comment: There's something funky going on when Crashlytics data is shown in BigQuery. The values in the array are getting mapped to 'build_version' and 'display_version', though I have no idea where that mapping is stored in BigQuery. Let me play around with your example for a little longer to see if I can make it work.

Comment: Hmm, dumping the data model shows 'application: STRUCT<build_version STRING, display_version STRING>', so may I'm not dealing with an array for that column, though it looks like it from the data.